# Understanding keyword self from LeetCode's Solution Class in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn Python and am practicing with LeetCode. [Problem 1721](https://leetcode.com/problems/swapping-nodes-in-a-linked-list/description/) asks us to write a function that will swap adjacent nodes pairwise when passed in a linked list.  For example:

```
Input : [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
Output: [B, A, D, C, F, E, G]
```

I was able to come up with a solution myself, but I don't understand this other solution below.  What exactly is `pre` binding to when the author writes `pre = self`?  My understanding of the keyword `self` leads me to believe it is referring to an instance of the `Solution` class, but I have no idea how that would help solve the problem. Shouldn't we only be manipulating the linked list?

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def swapPairs(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        pre, pre.next = self, head
        while pre.next and pre.next.next:
            a = pre.next
            b = a.next
            pre.next, b.next, a.next = b, a, b.next
            pre = a
        return self.next
```

I have read several other questions and other websites introducing `self`, but they all provide only very basic examples of constructors and other trivial functions.  I can't make sense of what `self.next` means here.

This is my first question on this forum, so if there is any way I can improve the question, please let me know.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses `self` in a rather "creative" way. Here `self` is the instance of `Solution` -- created by the LeetCode framework when it executed something like this:

```
solution = Solution()
head = ListNode(1, ListNode(2, ListNode(3)))
newHead = solution.swapPairs(head)
# ... continue to verify the returned result
```

To use `self` in this way looks weird, because that `self` is not a `ListNode` instance and has no `next` attribute. The following statement actually **creates** a `next` attribute on `self`:

```
pre, pre.next = self, head
```

As a consequence the loop will happily access this `next` attribute without having to know that it really doesn't belong to a `ListNode` instance. And after the loop ends, the `next` attribute can be retrieved to return the final list.

The author of this code thought to (ab)use `self` as a dummy node. It is more common to **create** such a dummy node, like so:

```
class Solution(object):
    def swapPairs(self, head):
        dummy = ListNode()  # The node's value is not relevant -- never used
        pre, pre.next = dummy, head
        while pre.next and pre.next.next:
            a = pre.next
            b = a.next
            pre.next, b.next, a.next = b, a, b.next
            pre = a
        return dummy.next
```

The author saved a bit of memory (and a line of code) by not creating this node, but reusing LeetCode's solution instance for that purpose.

I would not advise to do such things, because:

- it obscures the meaning of the code;
- it leaves a reference to the list on the *instance* of `Solution`. This is a side effect that the caller may not be aware of, and could prevent some garbage collection to take place.